# xcopy - copy files from the containing directory to directories on folder drag

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I have a `.bat` file sat in a directory with a number of resource .resx files.

When I drag a folder on to the `.bat` file I want to be able to copy the files that begin with the desired text (e.g. *Web.de.resx, Web.fr.resx* etc.), in that directory, to the corresponding directories in the desired folder.

I have tried the following, but I'm getting error: `File not found - Web*`

```
xcopy /i "Web*" "%~1\src\Resources\web"
```

Comment: You need to understand what is happening when you drag and drop that folder onto the batch file.  When you drag a file or folder onto the batch file, the Working Directory immediately becomes the path of that file or folder.  So in the case of your batch file you need to specify the path to where your input files exist.

Comment: @Squashman - need to use `%~dp0` variable - see answer from Cedric below.

Comment: I did read his answer but he does not explain why or what is happening.  I normally do a `PUSHD %~dp0` at the beginning of most of my drag and drop batch files. Sure you got an answer but you didn't know why.  So I provided the why!

Comment: Ok thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the directory in which your .bat should look for Web* files.

You can do this by using the "magical" `%~dp0` variable, with ~d is the drive and ~p is the path (without drive) where you are executed, so, ~dp will be the drive and path.

with `xcopy /i "%~dp0\Web*" "%~1\src\Resources\web"` it should work better.